# Open Graph object doesn't match meta information

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta

I'm trying to update the image Facebook associates with my website.  I've edited my meta tags and run FB's [lint utility](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=thegurucircle.com).  However, while no errors are shown, the og:image shown under "Raw Open Graph Document Information" does not match the og:image under "Object Properties".  Am I missing a step or doing something else incorrectly?